# DocumentDB / CosmosDB - Entity with the specified id does not exist in the system

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

i tried to connect documentdb from my asp.net website but i am getting this error.

**Entity with the specified id does not exist in the system**

DocumentClientException: Entity with the specified id does not exist in the system

code as follows in aspx code behind

```
protected async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("Page Load<br/>");
    await GetData();
}

public async Task GetData()
{
    try
    {
        Response.Write("<br/> Get Data function Start<br/><br/>");
        using (var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["endpoint"]), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["authKey"]))
        {
            //await client.OpenAsync();
            RequestOptions reqOpt = new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(209) };
            var parameters = new dynamic[] { 1 };
            StoredProcedureResponse<object> result = await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<object>(
                UriFactory.CreateStoredProcedureUri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["database"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pcsd"], "GetMemberbyId"), reqOpt, parameters);
            Response.Write(result.Response.ToString());
        }
        Response.Write("<br/><br/> Get Data function End");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

stored procedure as follows

```html
function GetMemberbyId(memId) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();

    //return getContext().getResponse().setBody('no docs found');
    // Query documents and take 1st item.
    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        'SELECT * FROM root m where m.memberId='+memId,
        function (err, feed, options) {
            if (err) throw err;

            // Check the feed and if empty, set the body to 'no docs found', 
            // else take 1st element from feed
            if (!feed || !feed.length) getContext().getResponse().setBody('no docs found');
            else getContext().getResponse().setBody(feed);
        });

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

in my localhost it's working fine but website published to azure web apps and running i am getting above error

Answer (score 14):

I just spent a couple of hours troubleshooting this, only to find that I had firewalled my instance to a point where I could not connect locally. Keep in mind that the Azure portal document query will obviously still work even when you have no direct access via the API / C# client.

Try setting the firewall to allow All Networks temporarily to check access.

[image: CosmosDB Firewall Settings]

Comment: Yep - can confirm this was the issue for me too.

Answer (score 0):

I would check in the portal that the "GetMemberbyId" is the name of the stored procedure for the collection you are trying to run it on. Could be the stored procedure is on a different collection or that the stored procedure is named something else.

If that all checks out.. I have had more luck with the __.filter() way of querying documents on the server. See:
http://azure.github.io/azure-documentdb-js-server/

Comment: In my localhost it's working fine but when i publish azure web app only i am getting that error.

Comment: Is the stored procedure only on localhost or is it published to azure also?

Comment: Is ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pcsd"] returning the correct collection on Azure?

Comment: Is ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["database"] returning the correct Database on published Azure app?

Comment: everything is fine in local and i removed from configuration and added statically... but same error getting

Comment: Does the DocDB instance block any IP addresses?

Comment: This is why I use a service like Raygun. I send the exception to Raygun and then I can see the full stack trace and error message.

Comment: yes it's in ip restriction and my ip is added over there... i test it without connecting docdb and i will able to access my data

Comment: I am stumped. Try contacting the docdb team direct. They are a big help