# cosmosDB/nodejs : Entity with the specified id does not exist in the system

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb, delete-row

I am trying to delete a record in cosmosDB, the document which I am trying to delete is available and I can access that but when try to delete that I got

"code":"NotFound","message":"Entity with the specified id does not exist in the system'.

```
 let deleteData = client.database(config.db.id).container(containerId).item(data[0].id, "/token" ).delete(data[0]);
deleteData.then((resp) => {
                console.log(`Deleted item:\n${data[0].id}\n`);
                return resp
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log("err in:\n\n", err);
                return err
            })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity with the specified id does not exist in the system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53506220/entity-with-the-specified-id-does-not-exist-in-the-system)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try setting the firewall to allow All Networks temporarily to check access.

[image]